# iPhone screenshot programmatically

Tags: iphone

I am new to Ios programming.I have used UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() through which taking screenshot of my app. Now I want to take iPhone other running app screenshot at background. Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: No, it's possible. This is a security feature.

Comment: Please make the question more clear and descriptive.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the response. How iTunes do that

Comment: @Goppinath  I am talking about how using xcode->window->organizer->  select device ->screenshot .this will take screenshot remotely. I want to take screenshot of phone at background .

Comment: Which is exactly same as home button + on/off screenshot but its impossible to do programmatically. But you can click the New Screenshot button to do the same.

Comment: iTunes connects directly to the operating system using a proprietary protocol. Obviously, the operating system has access to what is drawn on the screen, so it can send the screenshot to iTunes. You cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS has been implemented on top of [Sandboxing](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/) technology, kind of security. Therefore is is impossible to access the resources from the other Apps. So the answer is a big NO.

If its possible then you App can steel all the passwords and all other sensitive informations.

NB: Please read about Sandboxing.